# Login one account per device at a time

Tags: flutter, dart, go

I'm just new to flutter, is there a way to authenticate the user to only log in to one device at the same time without using firebase? I'm doing my research and all I'm seeing is they using firebase. My backend is Go.

Comment: Well..I think that  to do this, login session count is controlled at backend side.
If first device is logged in, increase login session count. And fail to second login.
If logged device is logged out, decrease login session count.